# Adding complex objects with repeating values (after parsing site)

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework

I have a task to parse some site. After parsing some post I have a complex object Post with a lot of Comment's, where each Comment have User who writed it and some answers in the form of other comments. In reality structure of classes will be more complicated, but well, here is example (some properties are missed, there no need in them):

```
public class Post : IParsedEntity
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public User Author { get; set; }
    public IList<Comment> DownLevelComments { get; set; }
    public IList<Comment> AllComments { get; set; }

    public Post()
    {
        DownLevelComments = new List<Comment>();
        AllComments = new List<Comment>();
    }
}

public class User : IParsedEntity
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}

public class Comment : IParsedEntity
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }
    public User Author { get; set; }
    public Comment ParentComment { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    public IList<Comment> SubComments { get; set; }

    public Comment()
    {
        SubComments = new List<Comment>();
    }
}
```

Now I configure my db context:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>().HasRequired(c => c.Post).WithMany(c => c.AllComments);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().HasMany(c => c.DownLevelComments);            
        modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>().HasMany<Comment>(c => c.SubComments).WithOptional(c => c.ParentComment);
```

Okay, I have parsed one post and now I have one instance of Post with a lot of instances of other classes linked to a main instance of post.

First problem: now I have multiple instance of one item  (there was two comment from 'nsinreal', so I have duplicate user instances). If I try to add Post i caught exception because I have items with duplicate keys. Okay, so I need to write my own TryAdd method that tries to add entity and all sub items; I need to merge instances with equal primary keys to one instance; And that's all must be done with using of EF, cuz my code can parse different posts and same user can appear in comments of different posts.

The second problem: I can't do it manually, because it can take a lot of time. I need to use reflection and make it works automatically.

Third problem: parsing and adding of posts must use different threads/tasks anything on one machine.

Currently I have recursive function TryAdd that makes suh steps:

1. Check that entity isn't already in context
2. Foreach property (only our primitive IParsedEntity classes) of entity do:

   1. Delete it from entity to prevent autoinserting of all entity with all properties. That's bad if you have duplicates like parsed users which appears at least twice in a post.
   2. Try to add value of property to database context and memorize answer. Must use reflection magic to provide normal work with generic methods
   3. Push answer of the database or original value of property to special dictionary
3. That same actions for IList
4. Add item to context
5. Recover all properties and lists of current item
6. Save local changes to database only once

Unfortunattely this algorithm have problems on different threads. How I must rewrite it?

Comment: Could you describe a little more the "Parsing"? Do you have Id's, after you pare you'r graph? Do you create the whole graph, outside of context and then just do dbContext.Posts.Add(post)?

Comment: Last. I have parsed post outside of context and then I use db

Comment: If you are setting the id's of the children objects, EF should handle adding only the appropriate objects to database itself, or just setting the FK on the parrent, if the object already exists in the context. There's still issue with the multithreading.. are you using single context (as in singleton or something) thruought multiple threads?

Comment: The problem: there are two diffent instances of one user: 1) new User() { Name = "nsinreal", .. } 2) new User() { Name = "nsinreal", .. } . And both are different objects. EF says that it can't insert second user, becouse first user was added already. When I add all Post to dbContext via dbContext.Posts.Add(post), EF automatically tries to insert both instances and I have a problem. I have tested it, simply adding doesn't work. I must to write my our own method that takes into account specific of my objects. Anyway, I think that adding two Posts with the same users will cause problems.

Comment: I use Ninject to get instance of repository. When I configure ninject to create only one instance in thread scope I got problems because I use async/await and Task (I think that some Tasks can use one thread). When I configure ninject to always create instance - I got problems too

Comment: NOTE: When I add posts one by one, there are no problems.